# Bings Ads Script - Calling Google Services not working

Tags: google-sheets-api, bing-ads-api

I'm trying to run a script in Bing Ads that will get the performance data and write it in Google Sheets. I based my code on Microsoft example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/scripts/examples/calling-google-services

However, my code won't work.

```
function main() {
 // Set these fields based on the option you chose for getting an access token.
  const credentials = {
    accessToken: '',
    clientId: '',
    clientSecret: '',
    refreshToken: ''
  };
 
  // To get a fileId or spreadsheetId, please see
  // https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#spreadsheet_id.
 
  // The file must contain a single bid multiplier value (for example,1.1),
  // which is used to update keyword bids.
  const fileId = 'INSERT FILE ID HERE';
 
  // The spreadsheet must contain 3 valid keyword IDs in cells A2, A3, and A4.
  const spreadsheetId = 'INSERT SPREADSHEET ID HERE';

  // The email address to send a notification email to at the end of the script.
  const notificationEmail = 'INSERT EMAIL HERE';
 
  var driveApi = GoogleApis.createDriveService(credentials);
 
  // Read bid multiplier from the file.
  // Reference: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export
  var bidMultiplier = driveApi.files.export({ fileId: fileId, mimeType: 'text/csv' }).body;
 
  Logger.log(`read bid multiplier ${bidMultiplier}`);
 
  var sheetsApi = GoogleApis.createSheetsService(credentials);
 
 
  // Write the old and new bid values back to the spreadsheet.
  // Reference: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate
  var campaignData = [];
    var campaigns = AdsApp.campaigns().withCondition('Cost > 0').forDateRange('THIS_MONTH');
    var campaignIterator = campaigns.get();
    var iterator = 0;
    while(campaignIterator.hasNext()) {
        var campaign = campaignIterator.next();
        var campaignName = campaign.getName();
        var stats = campaign.getStats(); 
        var cost = stats.getCost();
        var clicks = stats.getClicks(); 
        var conversions = stats.getConversions();
        var impressions = stats.getImpressions();
        campaignData[iterator] = {"CampaignName":campaignName,"cost":cost,"clicks":clicks,"conversions":conversions,"impressions":impressions};
        iterator++;
    }

    var updateResponse = sheetsApi.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate({ spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId }, {
    data: [
      { range: 'A2:G2', values: campaignData.map(x => [x]) },
    ],
    valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED'
  });
 
  Logger.log(`updated ${updateResponse.result.totalUpdatedCells} cells`);
 
  var gmailApi = GoogleApis.createGmailService(credentials);  
 
  var email = [
    `To: ${notificationEmail}`,
    'Subject: Google Services script',
    '',
    `You script ran successfully ✓ and updated ${updateResponse.result.totalUpdatedCells} cells.`
  ].join('\n');
 
  // Send the notification email.
  // Reference: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send
  var sendResponse = gmailApi.users.messages.send({ userId: 'me' }, { raw: Base64.encode(email) });
 
  Logger.log(`sent email thread ${sendResponse.result.threadId}`);
}
 
var GoogleApis;
(function (GoogleApis) {
  function createSheetsService(credentials) {
    return createService("https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4", credentials);
  }
  GoogleApis.createSheetsService = createSheetsService;
 
  function createDriveService(credentials) {
    return createService("https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest", credentials);
  }
  GoogleApis.createDriveService = createDriveService;
 
  function createGmailService(credentials) {
    return createService("https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest", credentials);
  }
  GoogleApis.createGmailService = createGmailService;
 
  // Creation logic based on https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/using#usage-simple
  function createService(url, credentials) {
    var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
    var discovery = JSON.parse(content);
    var baseUrl = discovery['rootUrl'] + discovery['servicePath'];
    var accessToken = getAccessToken(credentials);
    var service = build(discovery, {}, baseUrl, accessToken);
    return service;
  }
 
  function createNewMethod(method, baseUrl, accessToken) {
    return (urlParams, body) => {
      var urlPath = method.path;
      var queryArguments = [];
      for (var name in urlParams) {
        var paramConfg = method.parameters[name];
        if (!paramConfg) {
          throw `Unexpected url parameter ${name}`;
        }
        switch (paramConfg.location) {
          case 'path':
            urlPath = urlPath.replace('{' + name + '}', urlParams[name]);
            break;
          case 'query':
            queryArguments.push(`${name}=${urlParams[name]}`);
            break;
          default:
            throw `Unknown location ${paramConfg.location} for url parameter ${name}`;
        }
      }
      var url = baseUrl + urlPath;
      if (queryArguments.length > 0) {
        url += '?' + queryArguments.join('&');
      }
      var httpResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { contentType: 'application/json', method: method.httpMethod, payload: JSON.stringify(body), headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` }, muteHttpExceptions: true });
      var responseContent = httpResponse.getContentText();
      var responseCode = httpResponse.getResponseCode();
      var parsedResult;
      try {
        parsedResult = JSON.parse(responseContent);
      } catch (e) {
        parsedResult = false;
      }
      var response = new Response(parsedResult, responseContent, responseCode);
      if (responseCode >= 200 && responseCode <= 299) {
        return response;
      }
      throw response;
    }
  }
 
  function Response(result, body, status) {
    this.result = result;
    this.body = body;
    this.status = status;
  }
  Response.prototype.toString = function () {
    return this.body;
  }
 
  function build(discovery, collection, baseUrl, accessToken) {
    for (var name in discovery.resources) {
      var resource = discovery.resources[name];
      collection[name] = build(resource, {}, baseUrl, accessToken);
    }
    for (var name in discovery.methods) {
      var method = discovery.methods[name];
      collection[name] = createNewMethod(method, baseUrl, accessToken);
    }
    return collection;
  }
 
  function getAccessToken(credentials) {
    if (credentials.accessToken) {
      return credentials.accessToken;
    }
    var tokenResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token', { method: 'post', contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', muteHttpExceptions: true, payload: { client_id: credentials.clientId, client_secret: credentials.clientSecret, refresh_token: credentials.refreshToken, grant_type: 'refresh_token' } });    
    var responseCode = tokenResponse.getResponseCode(); 
    var responseText = tokenResponse.getContentText(); 
    if (responseCode >= 200 && responseCode <= 299) {
      var accessToken = JSON.parse(responseText)['access_token'];
      return accessToken;
    }    
    throw responseText;  
  }
})(GoogleApis || (GoogleApis = {}));
 
// Base64 implementation from https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/master/lib/msal-core/src/Utils.ts
class Base64 {
  static encode(input) {
    const keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
    let output = "";
    let chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;
    input = this.utf8Encode(input);
    while (i < input.length) {
      chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
      chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
      chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
      enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
      enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
      enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
      enc4 = chr3 & 63;
      if (isNaN(chr2)) {
        enc3 = enc4 = 64;
      }
      else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
        enc4 = 64;
      }
      output = output + keyStr.charAt(enc1) + keyStr.charAt(enc2) + keyStr.charAt(enc3) + keyStr.charAt(enc4);
    }
    return output.replace(/\+/g, "-").replace(/\//g, "_").replace(/=+$/, "");
  }
  static utf8Encode(input) {
    input = input.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
    var utftext = "";
    for (var n = 0; n < input.length; n++) {
      var c = input.charCodeAt(n);
      if (c < 128) {
        utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
      }
      else if ((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
      }
      else {
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
        utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
      }
    }
    return utftext;
  }
}
```

The first part of the code which brings back values from the spreadsheet works, but when it gets to writing the data in Google Sheets, I get an error and I don't know what it means.

```
{
"error": {
"code": 404,
"message": "Requested entity was not found.",
"status": "NOT_FOUND"
}
}

at (script code:142:7)
```

Comment: Hello, Are you running this code in Google Apps Script or where? And what line is line 142? It seems you are requesting a document that doesn't exist or is not found.

Comment: Hello, I am running the code in Bing Apps Script. This happens when I am trying to write data in the Google Sheet so the error is linked to Google Sheets API. Line 142 is 'throw response;'

Comment: the URL you are requesting does not exist. This leads to the the function throwing you the error.

Comment: The url is the same I'm fetching data from and that works, so the url does exist. This is why I'm inclined to thing it has to do with writing the data in Google sheets